# SQL result to complex object with children

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

We're looking for a more efficient way to build objects with full parent/child relationships than looping through the results of separate queries and assigning children to parents. It seems to be a big bottleneck in our code right now (we often need to do this with 1,000's to 1,000,000's of entities at a time.

Is there a way to use a query with `db.Database.SqlQuery<Parent>("SELECT * FROM xyz)` that returns parent/child/grandchildren relationships?

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Grandchild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}

public class Grandchild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using entity framework?

Comment: In Dapper you can do `QueryMultiple` which can pull out multiple resultsets. It also has `splitOn` which can split a single resultset into multiple objects

Comment: We're using EF, but the queries that it executes are sometimes incredibly slow, or it creates many round trips to the db when we can do it with one with a regular SQL query like this.

Comment: @Ali because we can cast the query results as a ViewModel we're able to set other properties of the ViewModel like parent Id's, etc. that are very helpful for what we're doing that we wouldn't have with an EF query

Answer (score 1):

using EF you could do something like this

```
db.Parent.Include(e=> e.Child).Include(e=> e.Child.SelectMany(s=> s.Grandchild));
```

using SqlQuery you should ensure the SQL SELECT includes all the necessary columns, using the aliases when necessary in order to match object property names

Comment: Would this execute a single trip to the database?

Comment: We were having issues with EF queries being really inefficient / slow / causing many trips to the db that we could do in one with a regular SQL query.

Comment: Using include cause single request to db. use profiler over sql or extract the commandtext to verify ;)